# How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?

Tags: sectioning, floats, positioning, page-breaking, sections-paragraphs

Often floats may land quite a bit later in the document than the point they are created, sometimes after a section break.

Is there a way to force a new section to start on a new page, after any unplaced floats?

Comment: See also the very related question [How to avoid splitting tables between sections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/how-to-avoid-splitting-tables-between-sections) for more possible solutions.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Use the [`placeins`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/placeins) package.

As noted in the comments, you can use

```
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

to automatically ensure floats do not go into the next section.

The package also gives you a `\FloatBarrier` command that you can use to prevent floats to appear beyond some point in your document. Use it as

```
% ... some floats here ...

\FloatBarrier

\subsection{My new subsection}
```

Comment: Instead of putting manually `\FloatBarrier` before each new section you can just use `section` option of [placeins](http://ctan.org/pkg/placeins) package.

Comment: @przemoc namely `\usepackage[section]{placeins}`

Comment: @przemoc Note, however, that this doesn't seem to work for subsections.

Comment: worked, great, should I remove format specifier's if using the \FloatBarrier?

Comment: @FilipeCorreia, I added `\begin{figure}[!h]` to the figure and it also works for subsections that way.

Comment: However, the `placeins` package does not ensure that floats don't go into the *previous* section, i.e. a float with `[t]` may appear above the start of the section in which the float was specified.

Answer (score 72):

The command `\clearpage` will not only start a new page, but will also force any unset floats to be set before the page break. For documents with a left and a right page, `\cleardoublepage` does the same, but also ensures that the next non-blank page is a right hand page.

This is all independent of the section break, save that if you are using a class that does not put a page break before section breaks, this method will force them. But, from your question, this doesn't seem to be a problem in your case.

Comment: This has been driving me nuts for 3 months. THANK YOU!

Comment: Simple. Full control. No extra packages needed. What else do you want?

Comment: This is not a good solution, since it requires clearing things every single time, instead of defining what one wants once and for the whole document. It clutters up the code a little bit.

Comment: When I place this command before a new section, figures from there appear above section name.

Answer (score 37):

I'm now using:

```
\usepackage{placeins}

\let\Oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsection}

\let\Oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsubsection}

\let\Oldsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsubsubsection}
```

This is shamelessly plugged from the union of this and other answers on the topic, plus [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245247/redefining-latex-macro-using-same-name). As I can't comment yet (silly requirement, that..), I'm sharing it with via a new answer instead.

Edit: Plus, for the sake of copy-pastability for others, I've incorporated egregs excellent correction to use the non-argumented version of section redefinition (before, the snippet above read `\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\FloatBarrier\Oldsection{#1}}` etc. - Thanks, egreg

Comment: Don't redefine `\section` with an argument: `\renewcommand{\section}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsection}` is sufficient and better, as it allows to still use `\section*{title}` and `\section[Short]{Long title}`. The same for `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`.

Answer (score 1):

Code works well for all sections and subsections for me , package needs to be updated on miktex package library

```
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\FloatBarrier
```

Above/Below every image or section

Comment: This doesn't add anything new to answer the question.