# Full-page figure without extraneous whitespace in text?

Tags: floats, page-breaking

My question is along the lines of [How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with), but slightly different. I have a figure that occupies a full page. By default, LaTeX wants it to go on the very last page of the document. The previous question was answered with Rob Hyndman's suggestion of using a `\FloatBarrier` from the `placeins` package to demand that it appears before the start of a section. But if I do that, I get a pattern like this:

> page (n-1): Section S of text ends halfway down the page.
>
> page n: Full-page figure.
>
> page (n+1): Section S+1 begins at the top of the page.

This is arguably better than having the figure at the end of the document, but it isn't the behavior I want. What I really want is the full-page figure in the middle, but Section S+1 beginning on page (n-1), so that the text flows normally from page (n-1) to page (n+1), with a page in the middle for the figure. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

The code looks something like this (`\FIGURE` comes from the `JHEP3` class supplied by the Journal of High-Energy Physics, but I don't think this is sensitive to details of that file).

```
\FIGURE[!p]{
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{curve1.pdf}&
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{curve2.pdf}\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{curve3.pdf}&
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{curve4.pdf}\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{curve5.pdf}&\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{curve6.pdf}\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{curve7.pdf}&\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{curve8.pdf}
\caption{Curves for case A (left), case B (right)}
\end{tabular}
\label{fig: constraints}}
```

Comment: We could probably do with an example. For instance did you try using the [p!] specifier?

Comment: I've tried !p, !h, and various other options. Details added; I don't know if they're helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) package might be useful here:

```
\usepackage{afterpage}
...
\section{S+1}
\afterpage{\clearpage}
% or \afterpage{\FloatBarrier}
```