# Forcing a figure to appear on the next page

Tags: floats, positioning, page-breaking

I have a figure which takes up an entire page of space.  When I use `\includegraphics` to put it in my document, instead of appearing on the next page, it appears at the end of the section.

However, I want the full-page figure to appear on the following page.  In other words, in the below MWE, I want:

(page 1) all of `TEXT A`, followed by the amount of `TEXT B` necessary to fill the rest of the page

(page 2) the full-page figure

(page 3) the remainder of `TEXT B`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \includegraphics
\usepackage{lipsum}   % for filler text
\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\lipsum[1-4] % TEXT A
\includegraphics{full_page_image}
\lipsum[1-4] % TEXT B
\section{Second Section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See [Full-page figure without extraneous whitespace in text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1061/2975)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `\afterpage{<content>}` macro from the `afterpage` package to place things directly after the current page. I'm not sure if you only want the image or a real `figure` with maybe a caption.

For an image only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % for \includegraphics
\usepackage{lipsum}   % for filler text
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\lipsum[1-4] % TEXT A
\afterpage{\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{image}}
\lipsum[1-4] % TEXT B
\section{Second Section}
\end{document}
```

Using a `figure` environment. The issue here is that earlier figures might be still unplaced and be then be placed before.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % for \includegraphics
\usepackage{lipsum}   % for filler text
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\lipsum[1-4] % TEXT A
\afterpage{%
    \begin{figure}[p]%
        \includegraphics[width=.99\textwidth,height=.99\textheight]{image}%
        %\caption{..}
    \end{figure}%
    \clearpage
}
\lipsum[1-4] % TEXT B
\section{Second Section}
\end{document}
```

This is similar to Werner's answer, but the `\afterpage{..\clearpage}` ensures that the figure is placed at the next page (Ok, this might be normally the case anyway). The `figure` could also be outside `\afterpage` and then an `\afterpage{\clearpage}` would be enough to flush it, but the code above is the safest IMHO.

Answer (score 8):

For this you need to make the image float. So, you should use (substituting `\rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}` for your fullpage image):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % for \includegraphics
\usepackage{lipsum}   % for filler text
\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\lipsum[1-4] % TEXT A
\begin{figure}[p]
\rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-4] % TEXT B
\section{Second Section}
\end{document}
```

Note that it is perfectly fine inserting a `figure` environment (that floats) *without* specifying a `\caption`.