# How to prevent reordering float appearance?

Tags: floats, floatrow, afterpage

Latex changes the order of floats in my document. It moves figure 2 before figure 1. Figure 1 occupies a whole page, therefore I set it to be inserted on a float page, in afterpage environment. How to make sure that all floats appear in the order they are defined in the document? Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\intextsep}{20pt}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{0.9\textheight}

\blindtext[8] (See Figure \ref{Fig1}) \blindtext[8] 

\afterpage{
\begin{figure}[p]
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
\framebox{\begin{minipage}[t][0.8\textheight]{0.8\textwidth}%
\hspace*{\fill}%
\end{minipage}}}{\caption{\label{Fig1}This is figure 1. \blindtext[8]}}
\end{figure}
\clearpage }

\blindtext[34] (See Figure \ref{Fig2}). \blindtext[12]

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
\framebox{\begin{minipage}[t][3cm]{0.8\textwidth}%
\hfill{}%
\end{minipage}}}{\caption{\label{Fig2}This is figure 2. \blindtext[4]}}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[10] (See Figure \ref{Fig3}) \blindtext[5] 

\begin{figure}
\noindent \centering{}\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
\framebox{\begin{minipage}[t][0.3\textheight]{0.8\textwidth}%
\hspace*{\fill}%
\end{minipage}}}{\caption{\label{Fig3}This is figure 3. \blindtext[4] }}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And the pdf result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Latex never re-orders floats (except for a bug in 2-column floats fixed in fixltx2e package) by putting it in afterpage you have manually re-ordered it so in that case you are  responsible for ensuring the correct order. Why use \afterpage here?

Comment: If you remove the `afterpage` "wrapper", the intended ordering prevails.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is a simplified example only for demonstration purpose. The original document is a multisection document with a lot of figures. If I remove \afterpage in the original document, the big one-page figure and all the following figures are pushed to the end of the section onto float pages, which is not acceptable. How can I prevent that if I remove \afterpage?

Comment: There are lots of answers on site for controlling float placement. hard to give any advice with so little information. The `\afterpage` usage here theough is simply wrong and will re-order the floats as you found. At the very least you should use `\afterpage{\clearpage` But I'd _never_ use a float in an afterpage like this (and I wrote that package)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. I see I can't use \afterpage like this (by the way I found that solution at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52515/forcing-a-figure-to-appear-on-the-next-page). I asked another question with another MWE where I don't use \afterpage: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233304/place-full-page-figure-float-after-the-page-where-its-referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing `\afterpage` is doing here is taking the floats out of the default ordering, just remove it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\intextsep}{20pt}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{0.9\textheight}

\blindtext[8] (See Figure \ref{Fig1}) \blindtext[8] 


\begin{figure}[p]
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
\framebox{\begin{minipage}[t][0.8\textheight]{0.8\textwidth}%
\hspace*{\fill}%
\end{minipage}}}{\caption{\label{Fig1}This is figure 1. \blindtext[8]}}
\end{figure}


\blindtext[34] (See Figure \ref{Fig2}). \blindtext[12]

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
\framebox{\begin{minipage}[t][3cm]{0.8\textwidth}%
\hfill{}%
\end{minipage}}}{\caption{\label{Fig2}This is figure 2. \blindtext[4]}}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[10] (See Figure \ref{Fig3}) \blindtext[5] 

\begin{figure}
\noindent \centering{}\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
\framebox{\begin{minipage}[t][0.3\textheight]{0.8\textwidth}%
\hspace*{\fill}%
\end{minipage}}}{\caption{\label{Fig3}This is figure 3. \blindtext[4] }}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```