# How to avoid splitting tables between sections

Tags: sectioning, floats, positioning, sections-paragraphs

I have 5 tables and a section after them. After creation of an output file I have two tables on one page, then a section and last 3 tables on next page.

What I want to achieve is to put tables and section below them.

```
\begin{table}[ht]\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
......
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:result}
\end{table}

\section{Section below tables}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the `\FloatBarrier` macro from the `placeins` package. This prevents floats from floating across the barrier. Alternatively, you can use the `section` option to that package to prevent floats from leaving the section.

Comment: I've used `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` and `\FloatBarrier` and tables are in fact above section. The side effect is that last 3 tables that have only one row each, take whole page... Do you have any idea how to  avoid this?

Comment: @pixel: You can try using `\FloatBarrier` in the places you don't want the floats to cross without using the `[section]` option. But without an example of what's going wrong, I can't really say.

Answer (score 26):

The easiest way is to use the `placeins` package:

```
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

Comment: Does it work for subsections and subsubsections also ?

Answer (score 8):

or you can change `\begin{table}[ht]` to `\begin{table}[H]` and add `\usepackage{float}` to your preamble. the `H` means "absolutely do not float this, and put it right here."

Comment: I continue to be baffled why this option is popular. I guess people who like to write "Here are our results:" and want the table right there. But, still, it's a perfectly good solution in this case.

Comment: @Will Robertson: My guess is people are so frustrated with LaTeX generally terrible float placement that they want to just say, "put it here, dammit!" One interface that I'd like is a way to say, "put this figure on page x", "put that figure on page x", "put this other figure on page y" and have LaTeX do exactly that: stack the first two figures on page x, and the third on page y. When I get into this position, I tend to move floats into their own files and then `\input` them and just move the location of the `\input` statement until LaTeX gives me what I want. It is suboptimal.

Comment: @TH., @Will Robertson: When I was still working with latex (a decade ago), float placement was also one of my major headaches always. The problem with [H] and [!h] was then that you end up having to add a gazillion of them just to prevent the float numbering from going out of order (table 5 appearing before table 4). A very nice feature in ConTeXt is that it automatically renumbers the floats in such a case. Is something like that also possible in latex these days?

Comment: @Taco: Not that I'm aware of, although Will would undoubtably know more. The LaTeX 2e kernel is perfectly willing to place figure 5 before figure 4 by default if one of them is a single column float and the other is a two column float. (In fact, a paper I was proof-reading for someone today had exactly this problem.) The fix is to use the `fixltx2e` package, but that just ensures the floats go in order; it doesn't renumber them if they're out of order.

Comment: I agree, the `H` option is pretty brute force, however, I write tech doc in latex for my company (I'm pretty happy they use it!) but I always have a ton of floats, and apparently it's too much to ask the user to turn the page to look at a table or figure. My company hates the `htbp` and I am forced to use `H`. But it does exactly what it's supposed to, and is pretty reliable, even if it leaves some suboptimal layouts.

Comment: @Taco @TH I'm just discovering the magic of floats :-) The [Tex FAQ page for "non-floating floats"](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=figurehere) mentions using `\Makesorted` from the *perpage* package to make sure the sequence of numbers is correct. (This info could be new since when this question was asked for all I know).

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `memoir`, it includes functionality from `placeins`. It allows you, for example, to do this:

```
\setFloatBlockFor{section}
```

which is equivalent to `\usepackage[section]{placeins}`

Answer (score 1):

The simple \clearpage command just before the new section (after the table) seems to work nicely. (in this case \clearpage does not insert an empty page)

\afterpage{...} worked OK but hid the section from the contents section of my thesis.

```
\section{Name1}
Stuff
\begin{table}[h]
...
\end{table}[h]
\clearpage
\section{Name2}
Stuff 2
\begin{table}[h]
...
\end{table}[h]
```

Comment: While this might somehow be a fragment of an answer, it's a fragment only