# How can I inhibit LaTeX to float a table across a section boundary?

Tags: sectioning, floats, positioning, sections-paragraphs

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>
> [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/5001)
>
> [How to avoid splitting tables between sections.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/how-to-avoid-splitting-tables-between-sections)
>
> [How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with)

I have a couple of tables that are written consecutively (8 tables) and after all tables, I start a new section.

I want that LaTeX floats all those tables in some way (order of them is not important), but that it floats them before I start a new section, as it's really confusing when suddenly a table of the previous section appears in the new section.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`placeins`](http://ctan.org/pkg/placeins) package provides a `\FloatBarrier` command which prevents floats from floating beyond it.  The package has a `[section]` option to place such a barrier at each section.

Answer (score 4):

Try `\usepackage[section]{placeins}`.