# Tables and sections get misplaced

Tags: floats, positioning

These are my tables:

```
 \section{The status of respondents}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
                \hline
            \textbf{Sl.No.} & \textbf{Grouping of Respondents} & \textbf{Respondents} & \textbf{Percentage} \\
            \hline
            1 & Students & 38 & 76\% \\
            \hline
            2 & Employees & 12 & 24\% \\
            \hline
              & \textbf{Total} & 50 & 100\% \\
            \hline          
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{The status of respondents}
        \end{table}     
    \end{center}  

Among the 50 respondents 38 were students and 12 were employees. 
\section{Some section}
\begin{center}
    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Sl.No.} & \textbf{Options} & \textbf{Respondents} & \textbf{Percentage} \\
        \hline
        1 & Getting it without making payment & 29 & 58\% \\
        \hline
        2 & Free to use it for any purpose & 10 & 20\% \\
        \hline
        3 & Free to distribute copies & 11 & 22\% \\
        \hline
          & \textbf{Total} & 50 & 100\% \\
        \hline 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Opinion about something}
    \end{table}
\end{center}
```

When I compile into a pdf the tables appear together, and section names and other writing in the middle will appear separately after the tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I inhibit LaTeX to float a table across a section boundary?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11791/how-can-i-inhibit-latex-to-float-a-table-across-a-section-boundary)

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9485/how-to-fix-table-position was a better match for a duplicate. There are many to choose from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

do not put the tables inside a center environment.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\section{The status of respondents}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
   \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}\hline
     \textbf{Sl.No.} & \textbf{Grouping of Respondents} & \textbf{Respondents} & \textbf{Percentage} \\
            \hline
            1 & Students & 38 & 76\% \\
            \hline
            2 & Employees & 12 & 24\% \\
            \hline
              & \textbf{Total} & 50 & 100\% \\
            \hline          
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{The status of respondents}
\end{table}     

Among the 50 respondents 38 were students and 12 were employees. 
\section{Some section}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}\hline
        \textbf{Sl.No.} & \textbf{Options} & \textbf{Respondents} & \textbf{Percentage} \\
        \hline
        1 & Getting it without making payment & 29 & 58\% \\
        \hline
        2 & Free to use it for any purpose & 10 & 20\% \\
        \hline
        3 & Free to distribute copies & 11 & 22\% \\
        \hline
          & \textbf{Total} & 50 & 100\% \\
        \hline 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Opinion about something}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You know this is a duplicate question; it comes up over and over. Just vote to close and give duplicate as the reason.

Comment: I used your solution and it worked. Among 8 tables the last table gets misplaced. Last table comes first section name later.  Any solution?

Comment: if you do not want that your tables should placed by TeX, then don't use a table environment, use `\captionof{table}{...}` instead (needs package `caption`)