# Positioning figures in specific places.

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

Whenever I insert a figure into my document, it is placed wherever it can fit. Sometimes this is before section that refers to it, which could be confusing to the reader if they see a figure before even reading the material that refers to it. Is there anyway to (at least semi) control the placement of a figure?

Note: I can kind of get it to work with wrapfigure because I can control where in the document it is place a little better...however, I don't want to wrap certain figures with text, so this solution doesn't seem like the best

Comment: See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/how-to-avoid-splitting-tables-between-sections), [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with) question.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I used [h] which works well for my purposes.