# How to place the figures in LaTeX document?

Tags: floats, positioning

Although I am putting the figures after some subsection, they do not appear in which I am putting in them.

Comment: Check the answers to this question: [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/2693). If that solves your problem, we'll close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/how-to-avoid-splitting-tables-between-sections) question. (That one is about tables, but the answers also apply for figures and custom-made floats.)

Comment: I used  \begin{figure}[!htbp]
but nothing happened.

Comment: well *something* must have happened. What do you mean then by "don't appear"? Are they in the wrong place, or are they not there at all? Do you get an error?  Do the captions show up, but not the figures? Do *no* figures show up, or just certain ones? You should edit your question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Alan Munn posted a link to [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned). Here's some code showing a way mentioned there, using the [placeins](http://ctan.org/pkg/placeins) package:

```
\usepackage{placeins}
...
\FloatBarrier
\subsection{A subsection}
...
\begin{figure}[ht]
% your figure
\end{figure}
...
\FloatBarrier
\subsection{Another subsection}
```

The `\FloatBarrier` command prevents floating of the figure into another subsection.