# How to bind figure (table) to a section?

Tags: sectioning, floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid splitting tables between sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/how-to-avoid-splitting-tables-between-sections)

I have the following problem: when I compile a document with text enclosed within a `\begin{table}...\end{table}` statement it compiles fine but sometimes the Table moves into the previous section.

Can I prevent tabular from moving floating environment within the document?

Comment: This is a frequently asked question and I closed it as duplicate to connect it to other previously asked and answered questions. This makes it easier for other people to also find the alternative solutions given there. It's OK to keep Thorsten's answer accepted as it is now.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the [`float`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/float/float.pdf) package:

```
\usepackage{float}
...
\begin{table}[H]
...
\end{table}
```

Alternatively there's also the [`placeins`](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/placeins/placeins-doc.pdf) package that provides `\FloatBarrier`

Comment: i was using h or ht but H did solve it