# Fixing the location of the appearance in algorithmicx environment

Tags: floats, positioning, algorithms, algorithmicx

I'm trying to force an algorithm to stay between two paragraphs, but after compilation, it shows up in the next page. My algorithm takes more than half a page and is something like:

```
 \begin{algorithm}[tbh]
 \caption{Game}

 \begin{algorithmic}
 \State  \bf{Initialize:} \normalfont 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \bf{A preferences:} \normalfont 
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 1 for A
                \item 2 for A
                \item 3 for A
            \end{itemize}
        \item \bf{B preferences::} \normalfont
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 1 for B
                \item 2 for B
                \item 3 for B
            \end{itemize}
        \item \bf{Nature sets the laws:} \normalfont
            \begin{itemize}
                \item The nature chooses a set of incentives $\mathcal{R}$.
            \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
 \State  
 \While {Set of Incentives $\mathcal{R}$ Exists}
 \State  
 \State \bf{Defend:} \normalfont 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item I
        \item II
        \item III
    \end{itemize}

 \State  
 \State \bf{Attack:} \normalfont 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item I
        \item II
        \item III
    \end{itemize}
 \State  
 \State \bf{Nature:} \normalfont 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item The Nature updates $\mathcal{R}$.
    \end{itemize}
  \State  
\EndWhile 
 \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

It seems like `[tbh]` is not working here.

Comment: Perhaps read [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT) to show why using `\bf` is not good use of font switches. Also, if you use `\textbf{...}`, there's no need for `\normalfont`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To *force* a float to remain in a specific location, add the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) to your preamble

```
\usepackage{float}% http://ctan.org/pkg/float
```

and use the `[H]` float placement specifier. Done.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% For this example
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,float}
\usepackage{lipsum}% For this example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{algorithm}[H]% Use "stay right HERE" already!
  \caption{Game}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \State \textbf{Initialize:}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item \textbf{A preferences:}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item 1 for A
          \item 2 for A
          \item 3 for A
        \end{itemize}
      \item \textbf{B preferences::}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item 1 for B
          \item 2 for B
          \item 3 for B
        \end{itemize}
      \item \textbf{Nature sets the laws:}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item The nature chooses a set of incentives~$\mathcal{R}$.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    \State  
    \While {Set of Incentives~$\mathcal{R}$ Exists}
      \State  
      \State \textbf{Defend:}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item I
          \item II
          \item III
        \end{itemize}
      \State  
      \State \textbf{Attack:}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item I
          \item II
          \item III
        \end{itemize}
      \State  
      \State \textbf{Nature:}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item The Nature updates~$\mathcal{R}$.
      \end{itemize}
      \State  
    \EndWhile 
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The reason why the float didn't stay where it was supposed to is because it was probably too large to fit within the page in the first place. See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764). Most likely variables like `\topfraction` or `\textfraction` caused the float to move onto page of its own.

There might be some drawbacks of using the `[H]` float specifier, although minimal. See [Drawbacks of the `H` specifier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161397/5764).

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of environments in `algorithmicx`.

1. One is `algorithmic`, which typesets algorithms very much like normal text.  This will stay between two paragraphs, if you put it there, but it will break across pages.
2. The other is `algorithm`, which is a floating object.  This means that it can get a caption, it will stay on one page and LaTeX will try to put it where you want but, pretty much, it will end up wherever LaTeX likes it most.

You are using the latter.  Your `[tbh]` directs LaTeX to try to place the algorithm alternatively:

1. Here, between your two paragraphs.
2. At the top of a page (it can be either this page or the next).
3. At the bottom of a page (same).

If your algorithm is not placed between your paragraphs, it's because LaTeX thinks it cannot fit there.  You'll have to decide whether you want to break it across pages (using just `algorithmic`) or to have it where LaTeX suggests.  Or you can force it, using the `float` package as in Werner's answer, but this will most probably look ugly.

Comment: not *in this order* it always tries `h` first, then t then b then p. _never_ use `h` on its own that makes the float virtually unplaceable as it prevents it being placed at top or bottom or on a float page (or at least ot would do that but latex2e gives a warning and changes it to th)

Comment: Fixed, sorry...