# Forcing a new section to begin after previous captions

Tags: sectioning, floats, page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid splitting tables between sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/how-to-avoid-splitting-tables-between-sections)

I have noticed that, by default, when you open a new section, it could interfere with the contents from the previous section. However, in my case I need the section to begin after all captions from the previous sections (figures, tables etc.) have been drawn.

I tried using multiple `\newpage` commands, but doesn't work. Any clever solution to this?

By the way, I don't mind setting some global document-level option so that it applies to the whole document (since I want to achieve the same globally).

Comment: The linked post provides a general method of avoiding these "interferences", while Boris' answer has to be used manually wherever you notice an "interference". Do any of these provide a solution? Let us know either way.

Comment: @Werner I personally prefer manual solution because in many cases I can tolerate floats slightly encroaching on the next sections.  However, I got at least one case when a reader of a technical document overlooked a float that was output after a new section started, so I might be wrong.

Comment: @Boris: Agreed. That's why, even with 2 closed votes (at the moment), I'm not sure whether this is a duplicate. Hence the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` command.  It dumps all floats in the stack.