# Why will my table not come after a section with \FloatBarrier?

Tags: sectioning, floats

I have been trying [this method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/how-to-avoid-splitting-tables-between-sections) to get a table to go after a section heading, but for some reason I am not able to get it to visualize that way.

```
\section{blah}
%\hlabel{sec:blah}
mytexthere (which is after the table... :( )

\FloatBarrier

\begin{table} \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| l | l |}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{config} \\
        \hline
        blah & DOUBLE BLAH \\   
        \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

%several other tables
\section{new blah}
```

Am I misunderstanding what `\FloatBarrier` does? I had assumed it will cause the final output of my document to be something like

1. Section heading
2. mytexthere
3. tables begin here

but rather it is:

1. tables begin here
2. section heading
3. mytexthere

I suspect `\FloatBarrier` is simply keeping those on the same page (which it does) but leads my question:

- How do I cause a table to always come after the `section` heading it is within? Can I do this with `\FloatBarrier`, or is there another way?

Comment: Try `\begin{table}[ht]` ...  The ht means try to place the table "here" first, and if unable, then place at the top of the page.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thanks - that fixed it. LaTeX is fun :)

Comment: `\FloatBarrier` has no effect at all on that table as it comes later, it is designed to stop earlier floats floating past (if you use the `section` option of the package it is added to all `\section` commands automatically).

Answer (score 11):

`\FloatBarrier` has no affect at all on that table as it comes later, it is designed to stop earlier floats floating past.

If you use the `[section]` option of the `placeins` package then `\FloatBarrier` is added to all `\section` commands automatically.