# Creating tables spanning across columns

Tags: tables

My problem is I wanted to create a table which is very long and spans across / continues into the next column. But the end of my table seems to be disappearing. 
My code is as below:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{array,supertabular,multirow}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
This is an abstract for a paper to show how to use latex for IEEE paper typeset.
\end{abstract}

Apart from that these applications needs  a lot of design perspective into these application as the requirement gathering for these products are not easy as it is challenging for the autistic children to convey their likes and dislikes in the first place. There are many studies being done in getting the correct design considerations and software attributes onto the application for autistic children. Some of them are stated below in the table. 

\FloatBarrier 
\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{A Simple Example Table}
\label{table_example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| p{0.01\textwidth} | p{.1\textwidth} | p{.1\textwidth}| p{.1\textwidth}|}
\hline
\bfseries No & \bfseries Title of article & \bfseries Problem addressed \bfseries & Proposed Solution\\
\hline
1 & Developing technology for autism: an interdisciplinary approach &   This paper talks about the various perspectives that need to look into from different disciplines (clinical, scientific traditions in psychology, HCI, education, social-signal processing) while creating technological aid for children with ASD. &   A design methodology which is a combination of Action Research (AR—from Education), participatory design (PD—from HCI) and Applied AI will help in providing a more meaningful technological solution as an intervention for autistic kids.\\
\hline
2 & Is simplicity the key to engagement for children on the autism spectrum?  & Interactive software which aims to help the autistic children can be inconsistent and has high level of complexity due to lack of consideration for implementation.  Example an  indication of a right or wrong answer , with a failure indication  less able children might develop  extreme anxiety and meltdowns, which are limits  learning and sociability&    This paper argues and proposes that simplicity  in design of interface is the key approach needed in designing software’s for children with autism or learning ability. \\
\hline

3 & Facial Expression Recognition Teaching to Preschoolers with Autism: A Natural User Interface approach & Children with autism have difficulties in recognition of affective expressions. Serious Games are said to be a means to help them, but most of  the games need to use mouse and keyboard, but preschoolers with delayed motor skills have problem using them (a known symptom of Autism) &  Developing a serious game with design concerns and specifications for preschoolers with delayed motor skills in autism will help them in expression recognition. \\
\hline
4 & Broadening Accessibility Through Special Interests: A New Approach for Software Customization&  Autistic children will usually have preferred repetitive interests, these unique character is said to be useful in helping them. By incorporating their interest into the activities they do, they will  participate in educational, therapeutic, or social situations  they might otherwise shun. This strategy has seen success in the research literature, it is difficult to implement on a large scale and therefore has not been widely adopted. &    The author proposes a software approach that can retrieve and process their subject of interest. And propose that a software algorithm will be helpful in aiding the autistic children and any software developer in designing a user interest  preferred application. \\
\hline
5 & Pervasive multimedia for autism intervention &  Paper based interventions for autistic children are unable to teach many concepts effectively and most if the computer-based support has targeted early detection and affect recognition but has not addressed automated stimulus generation. Some of the Proprietary systems, have limited content, deliver stimuli rigidly, and lack the ability to personalize delivery to the ASD individual. & The author proposes a framework for pervasive intervention delivery for ASD , taking into account, Learning theory,  fundamental tasks and generation of stimulus sets, Adapting stimulus complexity to performance and Delivery of daily lessons and predicts that it will be helpful in early intervention of ASD. \\
\hline
6 & Conversing through and about technologies: Design critique as an opportunity to engage children with autism and broaden research(er) perspectives  &    Involving children with Autism Spectrum Conditions (ASC) in design activities to develop interactive technology is challenging, because typical design activities involve complex social interaction between children and researchers which children with ASC find it difficult. However, this involvement is crucial, as the children’s lived experiences will necessarily differ greatly from those of adult designers. & The researcher proposes that development of a tool to support the contributions of children with Autism Spectrum Conditions (ASC) in a design critique activity can help them meaningfully participate in design activities.\\
\hline
7&  Design of a Gaze-Sensitive Virtual Social Interactive System for Children With Autism & Virtual Reality is used in promoting social interaction in kids with ASD. But these applications lack in personalisation. There exists no real-time system that can monitor eye-gaze dynamically and provide individualized feedback &  The researchers are proposing that a Virtual reality system that incorporates real time eye-gazing can increase the usefulness of virtual reality intervention for the kids with ASD.\\
\hline
8 & End-user programming architecture facilitates the uptake of robots in social therapies &    Although some easy-to-use tools for programming of robots exist , the major hurdle for using robots in everyday life is the difficulty to combine the expertise of robot programmers and developers and the domain specialists in the way that robots can be used to the state of the art of their performance by end users. &  This paper proposes an architecture that makes programming of robot behavior of an arbitrary complexity possible for end-users and shows the technical solutions in a way that is easy to understand and generalize
to different situations. It aims to facilitate the uptake and actual use of robot technologies in therapies for training social skills to autistic children.\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier
Apart from that these applications needs  a lot of design perspective into these application as the requirement gathering for these products are not easy as it is challenging for the autistic children to convey their likes and dislikes in the first place. There are many studies being done in getting the correct design considerations and software attributes onto the application for autistic children. Some of them are stated below in the table. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A comment: If you indent lines of code by four spaces, the site will pretty-print them as code automatically. The job of indenting the lines in question is done most easily by (i) highlighting lines and (ii) clicking on the `{}` symbol in the line above the editing window.

Comment: Is it just me or you are using longtable package but not actually using a long table?

Comment: Well I see you are not using the longtable enviroment in your MWE as @ajeh noted. According to the wikibook of LaTeX, **Long tables are natively supported by LaTeX thanks to the longtable environment. Unfortunately this environment does not support stretching (X columns).** I don't know if this would be helpful for you.

Comment: I don't understad why or for what(sic) are you using `\FloatBarrier` take a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102049/why-will-my-table-not-come-after-a-section-with-floatbarrier). I suggest also to check the [longtable manual](http://tezcatl.fciencias.unam.mx/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf) in fact, the pages 9 and 10 contents a summary of commands you can use for create tables.

Answer (score 1):

The content is far too dense for a table in my opinion; especially in a two-column format, but if you must, it can be done with `supertabular`. The `capt-of` package is used to place a caption outside of a float.

`longtable` would normally be my preferred solution for this, but it does not work in two-column documents.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{supertabular,capt-of}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{array,supertabular,multirow}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
This is an abstract for a paper to show how to use latex for IEEE paper typeset.
\end{abstract}

Apart from that these applications needs  a lot of design perspective into these application as the requirement gathering for these products are not easy as it is challenging for the autistic children to convey their likes and dislikes in the first place. There are many studies being done in getting the correct design considerations and software attributes onto the application for autistic children. Some of them are stated below in the table. 

{
\captionof{table}{A Simple Example Table}
\label{table_example}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{supertabular}{| p{0.02\textwidth} | p{.1\textwidth} | p{.13\textwidth}| p{.13\textwidth}|}
\hline
\bfseries No & \bfseries Title of article & \bfseries Problem addressed & \bfseries Proposed Solution\\
\hline
1 & Developing technology for autism: an interdisciplinary approach &   This paper talks about the various perspectives that need to look into from different disciplines (clinical, scientific traditions in psychology, HCI, education, social-signal processing) while creating technological aid for children with ASD. &   A design methodology which is a combination of Action Research (AR—from Education), participatory design (PD—from HCI) and Applied AI will help in providing a more meaningful technological solution as an intervention for autistic kids.\\
\hline
2 & Is simplicity the key to engagement for children on the autism spectrum?  & Interactive software which aims to help the autistic children can be inconsistent and has high level of complexity due to lack of consideration for implementation.  Example an  indication of a right or wrong answer, with a failure indication  less able children might develop  extreme anxiety and meltdowns, which are limits  learning and sociability&    This paper argues and proposes that simplicity  in design of interface is the key approach needed in designing software’s for children with autism or learning ability. \\
\hline

3 & Facial Expression Recognition Teaching to Preschoolers with Autism: A Natural User Interface approach & Children with autism have difficulties in recognition of affective expressions. Serious Games are said to be a means to help them, but most of  the games need to use mouse and keyboard, but preschoolers with delayed motor skills have problem using them (a known symptom of Autism) &  Developing a serious game with design concerns and specifications for preschoolers with delayed motor skills in autism will help them in expression recognition. \\
\hline
4 & Broadening Accessibility Through Special Interests: A New Approach for Software Customization&  Autistic children will usually have preferred repetitive interests, these unique character is said to be useful in helping them. By incorporating their interest into the activities they do, they will  participate in educational, therapeutic, or social situations  they might otherwise shun. This strategy has seen success in the research literature, it is difficult to implement on a large scale and therefore has not been widely adopted. &    The author proposes a software approach that can retrieve and process their subject of interest. And propose that a software algorithm will be helpful in aiding the autistic children and any software developer in designing a user interest  preferred application. \\
\hline
5 & Pervasive multimedia for autism intervention &  Paper based interventions for autistic children are unable to teach many concepts effectively and most if the computer-based support has targeted early detection and affect recognition but has not addressed automated stimulus generation. Some of the Proprietary systems, have limited content, deliver stimuli rigidly, and lack the ability to personalize delivery to the ASD individual. & The author proposes a framework for pervasive intervention delivery for ASD , taking into account, Learning theory,  fundamental tasks and generation of stimulus sets, Adapting stimulus complexity to performance and Delivery of daily lessons and predicts that it will be helpful in early intervention of ASD. \\
\hline
6 & Conversing through and about technologies: Design critique as an opportunity to engage children with autism and broaden research(er) perspectives  &    Involving children with Autism Spectrum Conditions (ASC) in design activities to develop interactive technology is challenging, because typical design activities involve complex social interaction between children and researchers which children with ASC find it difficult. However, this involvement is crucial, as the children’s lived experiences will necessarily differ greatly from those of adult designers. & The researcher proposes that development of a tool to support the contributions of children with Autism Spectrum Conditions (ASC) in a design critique activity can help them meaningfully participate in design activities.\\
\hline
7&  Design of a Gaze-Sensitive Virtual Social Interactive System for Children With Autism & Virtual Reality is used in promoting social interaction in kids with ASD. But these applications lack in personalisation. There exists no real-time system that can monitor eye-gaze dynamically and provide individualized feedback &  The researchers are proposing that a Virtual reality system that incorporates real time eye-gazing can increase the usefulness of virtual reality intervention for the kids with ASD.\\
\hline
8 & End-user programming architecture facilitates the uptake of robots in social therapies &    Although some easy-to-use tools for programming of robots exist , the major hurdle for using robots in everyday life is the difficulty to combine the expertise of robot programmers and developers and the domain specialists in the way that robots can be used to the state of the art of their performance by end users. &  This paper proposes an architecture that makes programming of robot behavior of an arbitrary complexity possible for end-users and shows the technical solutions in a way that is easy to understand and generalize
to different situations. It aims to facilitate the uptake and actual use of robot technologies in therapies for training social skills to autistic children.\\
\end{supertabular}
}
Apart from that these applications needs  a lot of design perspective into these application as the requirement gathering for these products are not easy as it is challenging for the autistic children to convey their likes and dislikes in the first place. There are many studies being done in getting the correct design considerations and software attributes onto the application for autistic children. Some of them are stated below in the table. 
\end{document}
```

[image]