# Preventing floats of being before section

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a rather large file with many chapters, before every chapter I use `\cleardoublepage` to get to a new doublepage but flushing all floats beforehand.

In the beginning I also had position specifiers on all floats but I then had the issue that all floats were pushed to the end. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11382/38807) suggests to remove the position specifiers, and that worked fine for me.

However, I now have the problem of sometimes seeing the following order

```
float
chapter title
```

instead of

```
chapter title
float
```

as it is in my document. I know there's a `\FloatBarrier` command but if I use it after the `\section{chapter title}` command, the float gets pushed to the next page, which is not what I want.

I wonder, how do I properly place floats and prevent them to be before my chapter titles?

---

A minimum working example is given here:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\cleardoublepage

\section{Section 2}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|}
    This is just a table \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a MWE (or two) where both cases are demonstrated. Normally, floats should be shipped out before chapters start -- I did not observe the behaviour you described up to now.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: You are using sections, not chapters, there is no automatic shipout of floats and new page before a new section starts. Perhaps, you have to change documentclass to `book` and switch to chapters accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fps@table{htbp}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\cleardoublepage

\section{Section 2}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|}
    This is just a table \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that this is working, not just for the MWE, but also for my main document. Do you mind explaining a bit what this `renewcommand` does?

Comment: It just changes the default position to add `h` same as using `[htbp]` on every table

Comment: Just as additon: [Why will my table not come after a section with \FloatBarrier?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104203).

Comment: floatbarrier stops floats floating forwards past the barrier it has no effect on it going backwards to the top of the current page. You could add `\usepackage{flafter}` which stops floats going backwards, then if it didn't fit "here"  it would go to the top of the next page rather than the top of the current one