# Forcing latex to place table floats before the end of subsection

Tags: tables, sectioning, floats

I have a chapter, where my data tables are big and cover whole page. I have few subsections with different results shown in tables and I don't want them to mix up.

So, right now I have more or less following layout

```
\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{results}
\subsection{Test 1}
1-2 pages of text here
\begin{table}[!p]
Table 1
... really big table that takes whole page
\end{table}
\begin{table}[!p]
Table 2
... really big table that takes whole page
\end{table}
\subsection{Test 2}
1-2 pages of text here
\begin{table}[!p]
Table 3
... really big table that takes whole page
\end{table}
\begin{table}[!p]
Table 4
... really big table that takes whole page
\end{table}
```

But what I get is more or less:

```
Beginning of "Test 1" subsection
Table 1
Beginning of "Test 2" subsection
Table 2
Table 3
Table 4
```

Is there a way to force full-page floats to place before the end of the subsection where they were placed?

Comment: I'm thinking (without testing it) that issuing a `\clearpage` before `\subsection{Test 2}` will clear all the floats.

Comment: since you are not allowing top or bottom floats the floats have to be on a page on their own so forcing a page break with `\clearpage` as Steven suggests is the way to go. If instead you allowed more normal latex float placement the placeins package allows you to keep floats in section boundaries

Comment: possibly relevant: [How to avoid splitting tables between sections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4666/579)

Comment: Both, `\clearpage` and `\FloatBarrier` methods work fine for me. There are some free spaces left at the end of subsection, but I will fill it with some pictures. Thanks, Steven, David and Barbara!