# Forcing bibliography to the end

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with)

I'm using the `thebibliography` environment, in a paper that has three floating figures. Now, for some odd reason, LaTeX is throwing two of those figures after the References, and one before, which seems to make no logical or typographical sense. It looks absolutely terrible. Why does it do this and how can I stop it?

Comment: This question, and the first two answers, are duplicates of questions and answers found elsewhere on the site, e.g. [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with) and [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

Comment: @mas: While the solutions in the linked answers also work here, the questions sees the float placement actually the other way around. In doesn't want to have the floats in their sections, but simply in front of the bibliography. Because of that the question could stay as it is in my opinion.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Issue a `\clearpage` command before the bibliography.

Answer (score 12):

You could use `\FloatBarrier` before the bibliography (from the `placeins` package).

You will find several questions and answers on this site relating to float placement and the reasons for their placement.