# Plots going to the wrong page

Tags: page-breaking, plot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

In the end of a section, I added two plots and. So, I finished this section and started a new one. However, this new section appears before the plots. To illustrate (apologies for non-necessary packages because I don't know which is necessary):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{listings}
 \usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

 \section{One}

     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 \begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.51]{bp1.pdf}
 \caption{Observed choice probabilities versus fitted  choice probabilities generated    by logit model using regression coefficients derived from TTO data}
 \label{bp9}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.51]{bp2.pdf}
  \caption{Observed choice probabilities versus fitted choice probabilities generated     by probit model using regression coefficients derived from TTO data}
 \label{bp10}
 \end{figure}


 \section{Two}

  cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
  cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc

  \end{document}
```

Here is the output. Note that the plots appear on the second section whereas they were meant to be in the first section

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code that compiles and shows the odd behavior? As it stands, your pseudo-code is not of much help to helpers. My guess though is that you have wrapped your plots in the `figure` environment.

Comment: @hpesoj626, please see my edited answer

Comment: Have a look at the following posts. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32598/force-latex-image-to-appear-in-the-section-in-which-its-declared. If this helps you, please let us know so that we can close this question as a duplicate. `:)`

Comment: @hpesoj626, the links have helped. So, feel free to close this queston :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have `\begin{figure}[p]` which means "on an own page" and the next page is after section 2.

Use `\begin{figure}[!htp]`instead