# Figures not showing where expected

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force figure placement in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text)

I have a a document and I'm inserting .png images but they are not shown where I want them. How do I fix this?

E.G.

```
\documentclass{report}    
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale  = 0.5]{Andromeda Galaxy.jpg}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\section{Section 2}
Text
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Other examples can also be found using the search function.

Comment: Where is the `\insertgraphics` command defined? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Also have a look at [How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with), which seems to be you use-case.

Comment: @egreg \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
is at the top with all the other packages

Comment: It doesn't provide `\insertgraphics`. Please, try and provide a minimal example.

Comment: Do not use the `center` environment, which adds extra (=wrong) vertical spacing, but `\centering` instead. Have a look at [Should I use center or centering for figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures).

Answer (score 7):

You are not stating where you want them to be placed instead, but I presume that you want to ensure that a figure for section 1 will not appear visually before section 1 starts. If so the standard LaTeX command to use is `\suppressfloats`in your case probably with the optional argument `[t]`to prevent it only from appearing at the top. You can also (additionally) add an optional argument to the `figure`environment to allow it to appear at the place it was specified if possible. So a solution would look like this:

```
\section{Section 1}
\suppressfloats[t]
\begin{figure}[tbh] ...
```

If you also want to ensure that floats belonging to one section stay within the section you could make use of the [`placeins`](http://ctan.org/pkg/placeins) package which provides a command called `\FloatBarrier`.