# Layout problems with tables and graphics (eps files) - they're all over the place!

Tags: tables, floats, positioning

I know I'm doing something dumb here but I can't figure it out.

I am creating a `.tex` file with a header:

```
%% XXXXXXXXXXXXXX created this file.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm,headheight=1cm,headsep=1cm,footskip=1cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={XXXXXX},
pdfauthor={Autogenerated by XXXXXX}}
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\usepackage{color}
\lhead{XXXXXX}
\begin{document}
```

Then a number of sections:

```
\section{\textsf{Section Name}}
```

Each containing several tables and graphs:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline 
& 1 Month & 3 Month & 6 Month & Average & Total\tabularnewline
\hline 
World&-12.6867&-14.984&-19.1529&-15.9345&-95.6071\tabularnewline
\hline 
Data Title&-12.6867&-14.984&-19.1529&-15.9345&-95.6071\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\newline
\vspace*{.25 cm}
\newline

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.8]{MyGraph}
\caption{World}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.8]{World}
\caption{World}
\end{figure}
```

Each section is far larger than a page, but before each section I have a

```
\newpage
```

For simple (ie very few sections / tables / graphs) the rendering to pdf via xelatex is often perfect. However once the document gets larger the tables are always in order but the graphs are all over the place - almost randomly.

I know I'm doing (or not doing) something really dumb here. I just want everything to appear in the order I write it.

Can anyone offer any assistance please?

Comment: Hi Tom, [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/9043). I removed the thanks which is just the style here. I also removed the sign off, which is not necessary as your user icon is placed with the question.

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat,  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`figure`s are floating environments, `tabular`s are not.  So the `tabular`s go exactly where they are in the source, but LaTeX puts the `figure` where it thinks makes the document "look" the best.

My understanding is that even with the `[h]` or `[h!]` options to the `figure` environment the figure cannot always be placed "right here."  LaTeX will disobey you.

A workaround ([via Mark Mengel](http://www-oss.fnal.gov/~mengel/How_To/node12.html#SECTION00052000000000000000)) would be to avoid the `figure` environment:

```
\newcommand{\figcaption}[1]{
    \addtocounter{figure}{1}
    {\center Figure \arabic{figure} #1\\ }
    \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{#1}
}
```

Then instead of a `figure` environment you can do:

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.8]{MyGraph}
\figcaption{World}
\end{center}
```

Another workaround would be to hack the float-placement algorithms.  But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The `caption` package provides `\captionof{figure}{This is the caption.}`. To avoid a pagebreak between figure and caption, perhaps a `minipage` instead of `center`? Lastly, the `float` package provides the `H` float specifier, which basically disables floating.

Comment: Ha, perfect, cheers!

Comment: @Tom: An upvote beats a cheers!

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  Agreed, the `float` package does the necessary hacking.  I learned about it after I posted, but got the upvotes and accept before I could delete my inferior answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing how large your figure and table floats are, it's hard (impossible?) to diagnose the problem fully. (From the `[scale=...]` options, though, I'm surmising that the figures are quite large.) You could try changing some of LaTeX's float-placement parameters and check if the float placement problems are at least partially alleviated. Start with the following settings:

```
\renewcommand\topfraction{0.85}
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{0.85}
\renewcommand\textfraction{0.1}
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{0.85}
```