# Placing the text in a new page after figures

Tags: floats, page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with)
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

I am a new user of LaTeX. I am facing a problem while trying to write a report. I have some text that ends at the middle of the page. The text is followed by a page which has only figures. I need the next line of text in a new page after the figures. but when i write anything new after the commands for the figures, LaTeX place the writings in the earlier page (after where the text ended at the middle of the page). Can anyone please help me with a solution for this problem?

Comment: Use `\clearpage` after your figure-environment.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Please post that as an answer together with a short explanation so that Hossain can accept it.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I think it's duplicated: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2279/5239

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: No, not really. This is related but not a duplicate. Flushing figures is not the same as fixing their positions. But there might be a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: @Hossain: There is also `\FloatBarrier`, see [How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279/2975). I closed your question now as a duplicate of this question to keep the site tidy. Also: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: this is so useful