# Image appearing in the middle of itemize

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they’re associated with?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with)

Basically I have something like this:

```
\section{first section}
[sometext]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{i/kbexample.png}
\caption{---}
\label{kbexample}
\end{figure}

\section{second section}

[sometext]

\begin{itemize}
\item An item
\end{itemize}
```

That image is appearing in the middle of my lists (`\begin{itemize}`). It even belongs to previous section but LaTeX prints it after the second section.

I know I can use `\clearpage` or `\newpage` but isn't that kind of silly?

Comment: Regarding the placement of floats in the section they belong to: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with

Comment: Please confirm if the link that lockstep provided resolves the issue- if so, that's great, and we'll close as a duplicate! If not, please say how your question is different :)

Comment: Yes please close as duplicate