# distributing each image in its section

Tags: graphics, sectioning, subfloats

Good evening,

I'm writing my thesis in Latex, with which I already had the pleasure to work for some other projects, but I'm now facing a problem I don't know how to solve.
I'll try to get to the point as straight as possible: let's say I have a chapter of simulation results, which includes a huge set of images. This chapter is subdivided itself in some sections, among which the images are distributed.
Now, what I would like to have is a way to have all the images related to section A inseted before section B starts and so on. I don't mean I want to precisely insert them where I want (the most of them are set of subfigures, difficult to be fit anywhere), it would be enough to be able to tell the compiler to put them all before the next section starts.

Do someone of you have any suggestion on the matter ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Michele

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your question sounds very similar to the one in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279/5001. Please take a look at that question and decide if using the `placeins` package and its command `\FloatBarrier` can get the job done for you.

Comment: Pay particularly close attention to the comment of the accepted answer to the linked question - makes things a lot simpler!

Comment: Have you tried `\clearpage` before the next section?