# Can I force the References to be the last thing?

Tags: bibtex, floats

I work in a simple document which contains text then a figure. It happened that there is not enough space after the text to fit the figure in the first page. Latex placed the figure in page 2 and placed the References at the bottom of page 1. It is not right for me to see the References before the figure. I want to References to be always at the end. However, in future when I expand the document, if it is normal text (non References) I want Latex to place the text in the empty space if the figure can not fit in that space. How to do this?

Comment: [How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282) might be helpful here.

Comment: You can try with `\clearpage` just before the bibliography or you can use the `placeins` package and the `\FloatBarrier` command just before the bibliography

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\FloatBarrier` from the `placeins` package. It prevents your floats from being moved behind this barrier.
Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{placeins}
\begin{document}
Some dummy text
Image
\FloatBarrier
More Text or your references
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `H` option for float placement from the float package, which forces the float to be placed right where you positioned it in your code.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum...
\begin{figure}[H]
the figures content
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be [h], but otherwise a good suggestion

Comment: @Dai Nope, the float package has the H option.