# Centering image

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I have an image in the document the problem is that when I insert it I have 5cm on the left and 0 on the right (the border is 5cm) I would like to center it.

I tried

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{image.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

and I even tried

```
\hfill\includegraphics[width=200mm]{image.jpg}\hspace*{\fill}
```

and even `\begin{center}`
but the picture is still not symmetric and I have a lot of space on the left but none on the right. I even tries `\centerline{\includegraphics{foo}}` but it gives me an error.

In other words I would like the image to ignore the margin.

Could you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE. How wide is the image, and how wide is the textblock?

Comment: The image is 200mm and textblock is 170mm

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth

Comment: Yes, the box trick worked. Thanks a lot. However, it would be interesting to know if there are other solutions that do not require the box.

Comment: Such as the `adjustbox` version? Or the second or third answer to that question? Or `\hspace*{-1.5cm}` right before your `\includegraphics`, for a bad solution.

Comment: The problem is that with the box it happens that I find it in the wrong section

Comment: That's a different thing altogether (and I'm surprised that `\makebox` changed the behaviour of the positioning). See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279, or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625 for suggestions on enforcing float placement.