# How to automatically add [H] in STATA

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have generated tables which all start with `\begin{table}[htbp]`.

However, to avoid them floating between sections, it was recommended for me to add `[H]` instead of `[htbp]` after `\begin{table}` and the use the package float. I was wondering if there would be a way to code in the esttab via Stata automatically, as opposed to change it manually.

Thank you.

Comment: If floating is OK, as long as it doesn't move to the next section, you could try `\usepackage[section]{placeins}`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279

Comment: H is useful for special cases but I'd be wary of using it by default.  tables are floated to improve page breaking and H disables floating so by design it produces poor white space by default, and forces manual control over table position which seems at odds with a generated document.

Comment: To avoid floating, simply don't use a `figure` environment, which only use is to float stuff.