# positioning an image in EUSFLAT 2019 overleaf template

Tags: floats, two-column

I am using overleaf.com to write a document.I am using [EUSFLAT 2019 template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/eusflat-2019-template/jmqvcrhkqhgx)
following is code which I inserted in this

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=60mm,height=40mm]{images/gcp_security_model1.jpg}
    \caption\label{ GCP Anomaly Detection}
    \end{figure}
```

this is how it looks like
[image: image of document]
I want the image inserted to come before `5 Footnotes and Citations` in the figure above.
The code of image is before Footnotes and citations section i.e.

`\section{Footnotes and Citations}` follows after the code of the image above.
I am not able to understand why is the image coming at the wrong location. The original image is very large in size.

Comment: `figure` environments are floats that can move away from where tey were entered in the code. Since your figure does not fit into the page it gets shifted to the next page. In order to avoid the bottom of the previous page to be empty, the text that was originally after the figure now starts at the previous page.

Comment: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/134144) , [How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279/134144) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but you will also have to fix `\caption\label{ GCP Anomaly Detection}` to something like `\caption{GCP Anomaly Detection}\label{myfigure}`.

Comment: ok as mentioned in this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282/208541 to use placeins package, how do I use package in overleaf I mean in which file should I put this or how to install package in overleaf template which I am using

Comment: Place `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` in the preamble of your `.tex` file (Between `\documentclass...` and `\begin{document}`).

Comment: you don't really need any package, just put `\clearpage`  before `\section{Footnotes and citations}`  but presumably the image you show is not generated by the code you posted as `\caption\label` must give errors rather than the output that you show doesn't it?

Comment: there are a lot of errors in my document which I see in log file section on overleaf. I am new to this environment. So I am not able to understand what to post and ask.Which section should I ask and like posting error corresponding to it I am not able to understand.

Comment: if you get _any_ error then do not even look at the generated pdf output or the positions of floats. TeX makes _no attempt_ to make sensible output after an error, the output is, at best, just of possible use in debugging.  Certainly fix all errors before adding forced page breaks to adjust float positions.

Comment: start with the first error (later errors are often spurious generated by recovery from earlier errors) and try to fix that. If you can not fix it, ask a question about that error,

Comment: ok just for information this is the image I am using https://cloud.google.com/solutions/images/partners/for-12.png how can I give reference to a URL in overleaf to mention from where I used the image.

Comment: that is unrelated to your question here but just say in teh caption or main text something like "`copied from \url{https://cloud.google.com/solutions/images/partners/for-12.png}` "   The `\url` command is defined in hyperref or url packages