# Always using `\clearpage` if figure does not fit

Tags: floats

I am quite new to latex, and am having some troubles in general with figure placementent.
Take this as and example:

```
...

\section{First}
Sample text:
%\clearpage
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Sample caption}
    \label{fig:sample_1}
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{sample/1}
\end{figure}

\section{Second}
Some other text

...
```

Now, if I compile the `tex` document and the image is too big to fit in the current page, it is often added **below the `Second`** section. So then, I have to uncomment the `\clearpage` to break the current page (up to `Sample text:`) so that the image is added on a new page and the `Second` section after that.

This bothers me quite a lot. I would much rather waste some space and always insert the image on a new page, if it doesn't fit. Is it possible to do so?

The main problem is that  if I add something above the code block above, then the `\clearpage` is used even if the image now fit, as `Sample text:` got moved on a new page by itself.

The strange thing to me is that I should be forcing the placement with `[h!]`, but it still doesn't work..

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with). Just load the `placeins` package with the option `section` in order to make sure that floats get placed *before* the next `\section` directive is executed.

Comment: The markup you are using directy works against your desired behaviour.  `\begin{figure}[h!]`  `h` (which almost always generates a warning, it should not be used on its own)  `h` means not at top of page, (no t) not at bottom of page (no b) not on a page on its own (as forced by `\clearpage`) (no p).  You should almost always include at least p and usually t and p if you use the optional argument.  Also only use `!` in exceptional cases (that is why `!` is used as the character).

Comment: Thanks a lot! The `placeins` is exactly what I needed.