# Consecutive figures in a section

Tags: floats

I am trying to display four consecutive figures in a section.
For example,

```
\section{S}
This is S

\begin{figure}[h]
\label{fig:F1}
\end{figure}


    \begin{figure}[h]
    \label{fig:F2}
    \end{figure}


\begin{figure}[h]
\label{fig:F3}
\end{figure}


    \begin{figure}[h]
    \label{fig:F4}
    \end{figure}

\newpage
\subsection{S1}
    This is S1
```

It is displaying the first two figures in section S and the last two in subsection S1.
How can I make all the figures displayed in section S only?

Comment: Can you provide a MWE. I cannot reproduce your problem. All the figures appear in section S.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/