# Drawing graphs of functions in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I have drawn  the following figure in Mathematica. It is plot of  `y <= 1/x`

[image]

But when I inserted it in latex using `\begin{figure}`, it was inserted there but I could not control its position in my document. Sometimes it moves into the unwanted position.

So, I thought if I could draw the figure in Latex using `tikz`. Actually, I want to draw the following figure ...

[image]

Can I draw the same graph as above in Latex?

Please help me.

Comment: Well, yes, you can probably recreate that with e.g. `pgfplots`, but if the positioning is the only reason you have for doing that, why not ask how to control the position of a floating environments like `figure`? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8625 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017 Note also that you do not need a `figure` environment to insert images. If you just want to insert a centered image at a specific point in the text, without a caption, use `\begin{center} \includegraphics{filename} \end{center}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw it in Ti*k*Z only, without using the `axis` environment (which I don't use, generally), here's a way to do that. It's what I use for my students.

[image: fill under the inverse function]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\xmin{-9} \def\xmax{8}
        \def\ymin{-4} \def\ymax{6}
        \def\Mgrid{1} \def\mgrid{0.2}
        
        \def\f{1/x}
                
        \draw[cyan!20,thin] (\xmin,\ymin) grid[step=\mgrid] (\xmax,\ymax);
        \draw[cyan] (\xmin,\ymin) grid[step=\Mgrid] (\xmax,\ymax);
        \draw[-Stealth] (\xmin,0) -- (\xmax,0);
        \draw[-Stealth] (0,\ymin) -- (0,\ymax);
        \foreach \x in {\xmin,...,-1,1,2,...,\xmax} \node[below] at (\x,0) {\footnotesize \strut \x};
        \foreach \y in {\ymin,...,-1,1,2,...,\ymax} \node[left] at (0,\y) {\footnotesize \strut \y};
        
        \clip (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
        
        \fill[red,opacity=0.3] (\xmin,\ymin) -- plot[domain=\xmin:-0.01,samples=100] ({\x}, {1/\x}) -- cycle;       
        \draw[thick,domain=\xmin:-0.01,red,samples=100] plot ({\x}, {1/\x});
        
        \fill[red,opacity=0.3] (0,\ymin) -- (0,\ymax) -- plot[domain=0.01:\xmax,samples=100] ({\x}, {1/\x}) -- (\xmax,\ymin) -- cycle;      
        \draw[thick,domain=0.01:\xmax,red,samples=100] plot ({\x}, {1/\x});
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```